# Save SKU from Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, controllers, admin-controller

I am having some trouble with Magento Observers. What I am trying to do is: as I am saving a custom product in my adminhtml form I want to my the product sku with a 3rd party API sku. To do this I created an observer for the save action (savePreDispatch) , able to get the retrieve the SKU from the third party API but now my concern is : how can save to my collection the retrieved SKU in the observer?

I have tried something like $this = $observer -> getEvent() -> getProduct() and then save the SKU but it doesn't appear to work, any ideas?

my config.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <namespace_module_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </namespace_module_setup>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <namespace_module>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
        </namespace_module>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <namespace_module>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
        </namespace_module>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <namespace_module>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>namespace_module_resource</resourceModel>
        </namespace_module>
        <namespace_module_resource>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <product>
                    <table>namespace_module_product</table>
                </product>
            </entities>
        </namespace_module_resource>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
  <events>
    <catalog_product_save_before>
      <observers>
        <namespace_module>
          <type>singleton</type>
            <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
            <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
        </namespace_module>
      </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_before>
  </events>    
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do notuse `$this`, an observer runs outside the product model. I do not suggest to use the predispatch action too, use the model save events.

Use `catalog_product_save_before` event in `adminhtml` scope.

```
...
<adminhtml>
...
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <my_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
                </my_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
        ...
    </events>
...
</adminhtml>
...
```

And do something like this:

```
...
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
...
$product->setSku($newSku);
...
```

Comment: Grazie @RiccardoT for the answer , however as far as I understand from magento the event catalog_product_save_before in the adminhtml fires up when I add a new product in the adminhtml right? However I want to fire up the same event but for my own module and for my products which are somehow separated entites, but I am having troubles in finding the right route for it, could you guide me ? Should it be something like <model_product_save_before> ? Thank you

Comment: Can you please add more details?

Comment: <catalog_product_save_before>
          <observers>
            <namespace_module>
              <type>singleton</type>
                <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                <method>catalogProductSaveBefore</method>
            </namespace_module>
          </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before> 

I have tried this code following your example but the event never fires up so I'm guessing it's some routes problem I'm missing out

Comment: Routes are not involved here, it should work at model level. Did you configure the "model" class path on your module?

Comment: yeah I am pretty sure the Model class is in place

Comment: Pls post your config.xml file

Comment: okay I posted it in my main post

Comment: It seems correct, pls also post your observer class

Comment: Well it's something really basic as I was just testing if it fires up : 
<? php
     class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function catalogProductSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){ die('I got here'); } }

Comment: Try (just for a test) to move from adminhtml to global. And of course flush your cache.

Comment: Have tried yet no success. It appears that the only workaround is to setup everything in my _beforeSave method in the model, yet using the observer was a little bit more elegant and magento way of doing the same thing.

Comment: That's so weird... we should investigate on it

Comment: yeah I know, will try to dig more and find a better solution to it.